# How to pass arguments such as username and password in a test

Tags: go, arguments, avi

I use below code to initialize connection to avi controller,

```golang
func TestAvi(t *testing.T) {
    aviClient, err := clients.NewAviClient("<CONTROLLERNAME>", "<USERID>",
        session.SetPassword("<PASSWORD"),
        session.SetTenant("<TENANT>"),
        session.SetInsecure)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }
```

And then I run *go test* command to run the code.
I would like to externalize CONTROLLERNAME, USERID, PASSWORD and TENANT. So that I can pass those as arguments to *go test* command.

Any assistance please?

Comment: What do you mean by "externalize"?

Comment: so that I dont have to put the password in the code, I would like pass it in command line like `go test -password=12345`

Comment: Oh. That's the opposite of externalizing :)  You want to read it from externally (aka internalize).  Environment variables are probably the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recommend passing those via CLI args, they are often logged.

A simple and most widely used solution is to pass such information via environment variables, which you can read using the [`os.Getenv()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Getenv) function.

How you set the environment variables is entirely up to you and may vary from system to system.

For example:

```
func TestAvi(t *testing.T) {
    controller := os.Getenv("AVI_CONTROLLERNAME")
    password := os.Getenv("AVI_PASSWORD")
    tenant := os.Getenv("AVI_TENANT")
    userID := os.Getenv("AVI_USERID")
    
    aviClient, err := clients.NewAviClient(controller, userID,
        session.SetPassword(password),
        session.SetTenant(tenant),
        session.SetInsecure)

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I added  `password := os.GetEnv("AVI_PASSWORD")`  under function
and added "os" under the import. Did AVI_PASSWORD="PASSWORD" in bash.
When I do `go test` get error `undefined: os.GetEnv`

Comment: @Simon I misspelled it, it's `os.Getenv()`. See edited answer.